Are "drive test" and "driving test" different?

This can be done by making driving tests harder: both written and drive tests must be more difficult so that only those knowing how to drive safely are allowed on the roads.

In the above sentence, it seems that this non-native English teacher, from whom I bought a writing course, broke the driving test down to two components: the written test and the drive test. Is this correct? Is the drive test even a thing?
P.S. I would like to understand why my question got three downvotes. Is it off-topic in some way? Please let me know.

The question implies that the quoted passage includes the phrase "drive test," but it does not.  Is everything as it should be?  If so, can you explain in some more detail why you are asking about the phrase "drive test"?

In the UK they're called the theory and practical tests, although the latter is often just called the driving test. If you want to know what the tests are called elsewhere, you'll have to specify a country/legal system.

You should also give an origin for the quote. If it's by a non-native why do you think it's accurate? Non-native writers use the wrong word often (as do natives sometimes).

Oh sorry. I was daydreaming while writing the sentence. I typed "driving tests" instead of "drive tests". I've just edited it.

@StuartF He's an English teacher. I just changed that detail.

I'd say it's 100% certain the cited text didn't come from a native Anglophone (apart from anything else, we say those who know how to..., not those knowing how to..., so it looks like "Indian English" to me). There's really no point in further investigation.

@FumbleFingers Oh that's something new. Does it mean that I shouldn't use "a reduced relative clause" after "those"? For example, the teacher also wrote: "those found running the red lights would have to pay hefty fines". Should it be "those who were found running..."?

Is he a teacher of Indian English? And is it their own writing course that you bought?

No, he's not Indian. And yes, I bought his course; he's an IELTS teacher. He's just a learner like me, but he's pretty famous and indeed he's a great teacher. However, as a non-native speaker, he sometimes does make mistakes, although this mistake seems a bit strange because it's pretty basic. That's why I asked this question to see if it's due to my ignorance or he is indeed wrong.

Why would you deliberately choose to study under a non-native Anglophone? I'm not prepared to go into great detail about every (almost inevitable) error such a "teacher" might make. Let him ask here if he seeks enlightenment!

Because that's what I can afford. Native teachers tend to ask for twice or three times as much money. Thank you for pointing it out, though. I appreciate it.

@AnIELTSLearner   Maybe your teacher said driver's test. Please get a clarification. driving test (also known as a driving exam, driver's test, or road test) is a procedure designed to test a person's ability to drive a motor vehicle. https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/driver%27s+test

These questions are getting a bit ridiculous now. This is at the level of "I found a scrap of paper on the ground that says 'no milk today thank you' - why is this not punctuated properly? Is it idiomatic?"


Is this correct? Is the drive test even a thing?

It's a bit weird, but I can't say for sure that there isn't some jurisdiction somewhere using "drive test."
The ambiguity, of course, is that "driving test" could be intended to denote the test, or part of the test, that involves actually driving a vehicle, but it could also refer more generally to the entirety of the testing, including the written portion (or even just to the written portion).  Resolving this ambiguity through a distinction between "drive test" and "driving test" is not to be recommended.
As noted in a comment, the UK uses "practical test"; in my experience in the northeastern US, it is most commonly known as a "road test"; I imagine that other terms are used as well.  I would be surprised if any native speaker regularly calls them "drive tests."

From another jurisdiction (New Zealand): we have a theory test followed by a practical driving test. (I've just checked the terms on the official Government website.) I personally have never heard of the expression "drive test".

Parking theory.  Traffic light theory. LOL

Theory covers laws, regulations, and good practice. You're not going to know the law on drunk driving just by driving around with a beer in your lap taking a sip and seeing what happens.

@TimR traffic lights in fact can mean different things in different places, especially those showing a green arrow.

I'm just chuckling at the use of the word "theory" there.

I was well prepared to barge in and assert that it was a mistake, that the phrase is "driving test" and that no one would ever say "drive test." But I bothered to google "drive test" first and found a number of relevant results, including from official sources. Note that you also see "drivers test," "road test," and other terms.
(Link is a pdf:) Colorado Department of Motor Vehicles driver handbook on p 4 has a section headed "Driving Skills Test (drive test)," and uses "drive test" throughout the paragraph. Similar for Washington state, California, Nevada, and (pdf) Texas. I stopped there, but there are probably others.
I guess I learned something today. Still, I would normally have said "driving test," myself. This ngram shows that "driving test" is massively more common than "drive test," and yet the sources above show that it's very common at least within official governmental materials.

I actually got 4 downvotes without any explanation in the beginning lol. I don't know why people downvote questions that include mistakes. Isn't this site for learners? I totally understand if my posts are downvoted because of the lack of research, unclear context, and the like; but for this?

@AnIELTSLearner Well, I don't know how many dated from the version that didn't include the word "drive"! But many might be reflexive from questions like this, following the pattern "Somebody (who might not be fluent themselves) said something confusing, and I can find no explanation for it (or haven't tried). What was their meaning?" For yourself, you might have improved this one by doing the same google search I did, "drive test," at which point the question becomes not just "this one person used it two ways," but...

... "I find it used two ways (and more) all over the place; what gives?" And that would also cut off at the pass all the commenters who were as sure as I was that it was not used, but didn't bother to check. (For what it's worth, it still sounds un-idiomatic to me. I wonder whether it started in some beurocratic source and got turned into a "governmental usage" even if it hasn't really spread to casual usage...)

Actually, I did do some research and found the same sources that you did. The thing is, I didn't expect native speakers to not know about "drive test" at all. I thought something like: Okay, it seems not so common. Maybe they'll tell me why it isn't common.

This sounds a bit subjective but I might be one of the learners who do most research before asking questions. It's just sometimes I don't expect things and hence my questions might lack some details. I am happy to add more information if somebody tells me to. But it's not always the case; sometimes people just downvote and leave. I think native speakers should understand that it's not easy for learners to ask a good question either. The language barrier is one huge obstacle, and sometimes there might be other unexpected problems as well.

Sorry for such long comments. You should have been the last one I complained to about this. I'm just a little frustrated.

@AnIELTSLearner By the way, I just edited to add an ngram: It's really true that "driving test" is way more common. Meanwhile: Yes, it's hard to write in a secondary language and you (and indeed pretty much any user here) are doing much better than I can in any of my secondaries. I think I've said this before, but "show your research" is not just a hoop to jump through, like "make them earn an answer by doing some work"; it yields better answers. If a question says "Is saying X okay?" then the answer is just "yes" or "no." If it's "... because source A says something that makes me think yes,

... but source B seems to contradict that," then the answers can be "Source A is just wrong," or "Oh, source A was talking about a different situation," or "Source B is actually using a different meaning of that word."
